# How to encapsulate string with double quotes using Python

Tags: python

I am processing D.B. Query using python and table name should be enclosed in Quotes to help possible escaping. Some time user provide name of table with quotes and some time with out quotes.

Wondering how can i make sure that tableName is always a quoted string?

```
my_string = "select * from " + tableName
print(my_string)
```

I want out put to be => select * from "table-Value"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your problem, you should manually check whether `myTable` is quoted by lines like

```
len(myTable) > 1 and '"' == myTable[0] and '"' == myTable[-1]
```

Then, you can apply the methods others suggest.

Also, I would suggest using formatting with docstrings because you can have commands that contain many lines.

```
"""CREATE TABLE {};""".format(your_var)
```

You can see it becoming useful when the command is long.

```
"""CREATE TABLE {} (
               pubkey varchar,
               title varchar,
               journal varchar,
               year varchar,
               PRIMARY KEY(pubkey));""".format(your_var)
```

Answer (score 2):

Two options, you can either put the whole thing in single quotes, or you can escape double quotes.

Option 1

```
my_string = 'select * from "' + tableName + '"'
```

Options 2

```
my_string = "select * from \"" + tableName + "\""
```

As an aside, for SQL queries you should be using prepared statements to avoid SQL injections.

Answer (score 2):

Try creating a string with single quotes and adding double quotes as below:

```
mystring = 'select * from "' + tableName + '"'
```

Alternatively you could escape the double quote within your String:

```
mystring = "select * from \"" + tableName + "\""
```

You can find more information on String Literals [Here](https://docs.python.org/2.0/ref/strings.html)

Answer (score 2):

You can use [String Formatting](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/string.html#format-string-syntax).

```
>>> tablename = 'user'
>>> query = "select * from '{}'".format(tablename)
>>> query
>>> "select * from 'user'"
```